# Reading from A json file, FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, json, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a simple app and im trying to understand how to read from a json file using a json parser. I wrote a simple json file and put it in one of my directories. Then I used right clock to get the path, and wrote the following code:

```
public void myParser() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    String path = "C:\\Users\\My Name\\IntelliJIDEAProjects\\Intereview\\app\\src\\main\\res\\Data\\dataStructures.json";

    try{
        JSONArray topics = (JSONArray)parser.parse(new FileReader(path));
        for(int i=0;i<topics.length();i++) {
            JSONObject object = topics.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = object.optString("title").toString();
            Log.i(TAG,title);
        }

    }

    catch(JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Internal Problem", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

from some reason, i get this error when running the app:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\My Name\IntelliJIDEAProjects\Intereview\app\src\main\res\Data\dataStructures.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

what could be the reason behind that? i've been working on this for the past few hours and I just can't figure it out..
Thanks

Comment: I think The message is pretty clear. Mybe a type here: `Intereview`?

Comment: You are running the application either in phone or in emulator and giving path of Computer disk how is it possible?

Comment: no buddy, thats the name of the app.. typo is on purpose

Comment: I thought i could run it in the emulator since the file in the app directory no? How can i solve this then?

Answer (score 1):

You have [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) on this question, so I assume that you are trying to write an Android app. If so, this will not work:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\My Name\\IntelliJIDEAProjects\\Intereview\\app\\src\\main\\res\\Data\\dataStructures.json";
```

My guess, based on that path, is that you are trying to package a JSON file with your app. In that case, you cannot create random directories under `res/` either. Even if this JSON file were in a proper `res/` directory (e.g., `res/raw/`), you cannot access it via a `FileReader`. It is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the Android device.

Your two main options are:

1. Move that JSON file from `res/Data/` into `res/raw/`. Then, use `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dataStructures)` to get an `InputStream` on the JSON.
2. Move that JSON file from `res/Data/` into `assets/`. Then, use `getAssets().open("dataStructures.json")` to get an `InputStream` on the JSON.

Note that `getResources()` and `getAssets()` are methods on `Context` and its subclasses, such as `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer, I just started using json so I dont really get it yet. The only thing I dont understand now, is how would you create JSONObject using the parser? The parse method accepts a Reader or a String. Basically, how would I convert from inputStream to Reader/String?

Comment: @baki1995: Use [an `InputStreamReader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Answer (score 0):

This appears when the file isn't there...

Check the spelling of your pathname `(intereview?)` and... check if the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put json inside the assets folder.

1. In the perspective window open the Project Perspective.
2. Create the directory inside your android_test/test folder with name                      assets depending upon where you need the JSON response
3. Now simple put your JSON file inside the assets folder
4. And call your JSON by simply calling their single name like xyz.json